# Scrapy : xpath of a link in a table

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

I would like to extract some book links from this table using scrapy.

The table looks like this :

```
<table id="table_text">

<tbody>

<tr >
<td>15/02/2014</td>
<td><a href="/book_1.html">Book 1</a></td>
<td>The Author</td>
<td> <a href="/tag1">tag1</a>  <a href="/tag2">tag2</a> </td>
<td>Genre</td>
</tr>
```

and the extracted link should be :

```
/book_1.html
```

The selector that I used is

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    hxs = Selector(response)
    links = hxs.xpath('//table[@id="table_text"]//tr//td[2]//a//@href')
```

but `print links` shows an empty output : `[]`

I would like to know what is wrong with the `xpath` that I used ?

Comment: A complete reproducer (that is to say, something we can run ourselves to reproduce) would be more helpful. Is the page publicly available?

Comment: By the way, you're using a lot more `//`s than you need to. Many of those will only ever be single hops.

Comment: You could simplify with `//table[@id="table_text"]//tr/td[2]/a/@href`, but with what you've described the XPath is working. Can you give more context? More HTML? Did you check the body in `response` *is* actually the one you think it is (browsers can display a different HTML from what scrapy retrieves, coz of JS for example)?

Comment: @Robin Thanks, I checked `response.body` and the HTML code is different from what Firefox or Chrome gives because of JS :-) The table was built with `new Array()` instead of HTML .

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll post the comment as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the information you gave, your XPath is working fine. It could be simplified with

```
//table[@id="table_text"]//tr/td[2]/a/@href
```

but your version returns the right node.

When encountering unexpected behavior with scrapy, try to always check the HTML it receives is the one that you expected. **HTML retrieved with browsers and with scrapy may be different**, because scrapy doesn't handle Javascript (and some browsers try to sanitize HTML).

That's why you should **check** that the content of **response.body is what you expect**. If it's not, you'll need to find a workaround :)